# Kernel ridge regression (KRR), accuracy scale?

Tags: regression, accuracy, model-selection, kernel

What does a good range for the accuracy score look like for the KRR model?

For example, RMSE produces a value between 0 and 1, where values closer to 0 represent better fitting models. What's the equivalent in KRR?

Comment: If RMSE stands for Root Mean Squared Error, then the value is not restricted to lie in the interval between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

In a regression problem you have a set of observations $\mathcal{D}:= \{(x_{n},y_{n})\}_{n=1}^{N}$ with $x_{n}\in X \subset \mathbb{R}^{k}$ and $y_{n}\in Y \subset \mathbb{R}$. The assumption is that there exists a function
$$f:X \rightarrow Y\; \text{ such that}\; y_{n}=f(x_{n})+\varepsilon_{n}$$ with $\varepsilon_{n} \sim Normal(0,\sigma^{2})$ for $n=1,\ldots,N$.

The goal is to find a function which get's as close as possible to the function $f$ which is usually measured using an error metric $d$.
Examples are

- MSE=Mean Squared Error $MSE(y,\hat{y})=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i}\right)$
- RMSE=Root Mean Squared Error $RMSE(y,\hat{y})=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i}\right)}$.

with $\hat{y}_{i}$ being the prediction for observation $i$.

From a high level, Kernel Ridge Regression is just one of many regression models, Linear Regression and Random Forest are other examples, that are used to approximate $f$.

Independent of your model is the error metric which is used to choose among your models, f.e. one model vs. another or which features to use in your model.
As the error metric measures the discrepancy between your predictions and the true value, smaller values are better.

Therefore one cannot answer the question in general which values of the RMSE are good given you use Kernel Ridge Regression but only compare between Kernel Ridge Regression with different kernels or between Kernel Ridge Regression and a Linear Model and choose the one with the smallest error metric.

Comment: I understand, thank you for taking the time answer!